# send data using okhttp without async task

Tags: android, okhttp

Can I use this way to upload string to server using `Okhttp` ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

     usernam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
     passw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
     email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

     name = usernam.getText().toString();
     pass = passw.getText().toString();
     emails = email.getText().toString();

}


private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception {
    String json = "";

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.accumulate("name",name );
    jsonObject.accumulate("password",pass );
    jsonObject.accumulate("email",emails );

    json = jsonObject.toString();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
            .add("result", json)
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://justedhak.comlu.com/receiver.php")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

Comment: May be include with reactive programming, like rx-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use OkHttp without AsyncTask, you can refer to the following sample code, hope this helps!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "OkHttp";
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private String mMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        // GET request
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://...")
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                mMessage = e.toString();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, mMessage); // no need inside run()
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mTextView.setText(mMessage); // must be inside run()
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                mMessage = response.toString();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, mMessage); // no need inside run()
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mTextView.setText(mMessage); // must be inside run()
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hey man thanks for your answer , in this code what are you retreiving ? I what if I want to retrieve a specefic value from the database ? should we add a Body ?, and What if i want to send something to the database ? I use inputsream or what ?

Comment: The response is the same as sync way, if you want to send data, use POST request

Answer (score 1):

network calls must be completed off of the UI thread, so no.

Also you never call your Run() method in your activity, so it would not be executed

EDIT: Max Pino is correct in that RXJava can be used to make this kind of call easily, however, that will still execute the call on a different thread

Comment: I have never used rx java , ill use my method using async task, btw is it correct adding json like this code ?             .add("result", json)

Comment: I am not sure about your JSON question but heres how I went about using RX in a auto correct situation that required an async task if you are interested:  
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415151/asynctask-replacement-with-rxjava-help-needed/33421148#33421148
Please mark my answer as correct if it helped you!

Comment: than you  for your help, ill ask another question related to my json, can you chek it please ? this is the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486899/json-object-and-okhttp-sending-data